# How to solve wordpress redirect with parameter 404 error?

Tags: php, wordpress

i am new in wordpress and i am going to replace the search url with my own page, but when i hit the page and it show me 404 error.

It works without any parameter (http://harsimranjit.vintage-comics.net/products/)

but with parameter not (http://harsimranjit.vintage-comics.net/products/?s=bag).

Please help me to solve this problem. i am using wordpress default theme twenty-twenty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a function to tell WordPress to keep track of our new query variables

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
$aVars[] = "products"; 
return $aVars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

you also need to tell WordPress how to populate that query variable

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array('products/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=products&s=$matches[1]');
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
return $aRules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

you can't just use the $_GET superglobal to grab our query variable

Instead you have to access the query_vars property of the $wp_query object.

```
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['s'])) {
$sMsdsCat = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['s']);
}
```

[Passing Query String Parameters In WordPress URL](https://www.uforocks.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url)